# How to split comma separated values into multiple rows through query using mysql

Tags: mysql

Suppose I have the data like this:-

```
LOC_ ADDR_SR LOADTYPE WEEKDAY 
AANDCHVA     Frozen   Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday 
ABPMN        Frozen   Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday 
ACMEC        Frozen   Tuesday, Wednesday 
ACMER        Frozen   Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday 
ACOSALNM     Frozen   Wednesday, Thursday 
ACOSBLNJ     Frozen   Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday 
ACOSKEWA     Frozen   Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday 
ACOSLUTX     Frozen   Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday
```

I want to split the "weekday" column into multiple rows.

example output should be like:-

[image: example output should be like this:]

Comment: Specify PRECISE MySQL version.

Answer (score 0):

I have a table integers (ints(i)) with values 0-9...

```
SELECT DISTINCT LOC_ADDR_SR
              , LOADTYPE
              , TRIM(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(WEEKDAY,',',i+1),',',-1)) x
           FROM my_table
              , ints
          ORDER
             BY LOC_ADDR_SR
              , i;

+-------------+----------+-----------+
| LOC_ADDR_SR | LOADTYPE | x         |
+-------------+----------+-----------+
| AANDCHVA    | Frozen   | Monday    |
| AANDCHVA    | Frozen   | Tuesday   |
| AANDCHVA    | Frozen   | Wednesday |
| AANDCHVA    | Frozen   | Thursday  |
| AANDCHVA    | Frozen   | Friday    |
| ABPMN       | Frozen   | Monday    |
| ABPMN       | Frozen   | Tuesday   |
| ABPMN       | Frozen   | Wednesday |
| ABPMN       | Frozen   | Thursday  |
| ABPMN       | Frozen   | Friday    |
| ACMEC       | Frozen   | Tuesday   |
| ACMEC       | Frozen   | Wednesday |
| ACMER       | Frozen   | Monday    |
| ACMER       | Frozen   | Tuesday   |
| ACMER       | Frozen   | Wednesday |
| ACMER       | Frozen   | Thursday  |
| ACMER       | Frozen   | Friday    |
| ACOSALNM    | Frozen   | Wednesday |
| ACOSALNM    | Frozen   | Thursday  |
| ACOSBLNJ    | Frozen   | Monday    |
| ACOSBLNJ    | Frozen   | Tuesday   |
| ACOSBLNJ    | Frozen   | Wednesday |
| ACOSBLNJ    | Frozen   | Thursday  |
| ACOSBLNJ    | Frozen   | Friday    |
| ACOSKEWA    | Frozen   | Monday    |
| ACOSKEWA    | Frozen   | Tuesday   |
| ACOSKEWA    | Frozen   | Wednesday |
| ACOSLUTX    | Frozen   | Tuesday   |
| ACOSLUTX    | Frozen   | Wednesday |
| ACOSLUTX    | Frozen   | Thursday  |
+-------------+----------+-----------+
```